# Passing model to view optionally

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, view, model

I have a form that is being used to edit existing object as well as to enter a new one.

When I am using it to edit, i pass the model to the view inside the action like this

```
 return View("Details", myModelObject);
```

When I am using the Details view to enter the new object, I am not passing anything

```
return View("Details");
```

I am getting en error because the framework expects the model to be passed in as at the beggining of the view I have

```
@model myApp.Models.myModel
```

One way to get around is to pass an empty model, but this seems kind of awkward and unnecessary. Is there a way to indicate that @model is optional?

Comment: Did you try to check if the model is passed or not in your view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> One way to get around is to pass an empty model, but this seems kind
>   of awkward and unnecessary

This is the correct way. Your view expects a model. Since this view is intended for creating a new model, passing a new instance of the model is very natural:

```
return View("Details", new MyViewModel());
```